# Android browser floating menu issue while fast scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with fixed floating menu on android phones browsers (not tested on other phones) and still can't find any solution.

Let's take this as an example: (the first link I found on google)
http://www.backslash.gr/demos/jquery-sticky-navigation/

Scrolling and clicking on menu works, but if I make fast scroll and let the scroll stop automatically 'til it reaches phone browser's bottom or top, the floating menu becomes inactive (not able to click on floating menu, focus-link position is changed). If I make fast scroll and stop scrolling by touching the screen (don't let the scroll to reach bottom or top and stop automatically) the floating menu works and links are active.

I have tried about 10-20 examples I found on google, even bootstrap has the same issue.
Also tried libraries like *mCustomScroll* and *iscrool*, but they are too slow for phone browser or have other issues.

Tested on android > 4.x several different phones and versions.

I hope you understood the problem and can suggest anything.
Also it would be nice if anybody could test it on iphone (but I think its Android problem).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found good enough solution https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/
So I was able to create fast scrolling page and make workaround for described bug.